# Getting connection refused error when trying to connect to aws ec2 on a specific port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

We are trying to use ssh tunnel local port forwarding on aws ec2,that should forward the requests to DocumentDB.

```
 sudo ssh -L 27777:docdbid***.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ec2-user@localhost -i "ec2keypair.pem" -N
```

Using netstat command(`netstat -ano|grep 27777`),we got to know the port is listening on aws ec2.But,using telnet command from our machine and from our mongodb application,we get connection refused error when we try to connect to ec2 instance on 27777,where as we can ssh in to ec2 instance from our machine(`ssh -i "ec2keypair.pem" ec2-user@ec2*****.compute.amazonaws.com`).With telnet command,we get exception as `Could not open connection to the host, on port 27777: Connect failed`.The port is open in aws security group and also in our machine firewall inbound and outbound rules.Can anyone let us know the reason for the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the replica set from application via SSH tunneling? If yes, replica set does not work with tunneling
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/documentdb-cannot-connect/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the command like below:

`ssh -L 27777:docdbid***.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 -i "ec2keypair.pem" ec2-user@ec2***.compute.amazonaws.com`

Basically port forwarding command should like this `ssh -L [LOCAL_IP:]LOCAL_PORT:DESTINATION:DESTINATION_PORT [USER@]SSH_SERVER`.

See [Reference](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ssh-tunneling/).